onFocus does not run a function in TextInput in react native
<TextInput 
    placeHolder="I was approached and ..."
    onChangeText={(desc) => dispatch(updateErrorPageDesc(desc))}
    onFocus= {testFunction}
/>

const testFunction = () => {
    console.log("my typing ");
}

Console.log does not get called when I click on the TextInput
I expect "my typing " to be outputted to the console when I click on the TextInput
The onChangeText works well. The onFocus doesn't do anything!

const testFunction = (event) => {
    console.log("my typing ");
}

All it needed was the word event in the braces and everything worked.
